# Is there a difference between negligible and neglectable?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

According to [wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negligible) they are synonyms. However, most words have a slight difference in the way or in which context they are used. I would like to know those differences.

For example, when one has two mathematical models that describe data where you have an error measure to see their performance. Would you rather say A) or B) or is it really synonymous?

> A) The performance differences of model alpha and model beta are negligible.
>
> B) The performance differences of model alpha and model beta are neglectable.

Comment: The most obvious difference is that [written instances of "are neglectable" are negligible by comparison with "are negligible"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+negligible%2Care+neglectable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20negligible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20neglectable%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for that! I always forget Google nGrams (and nice word play ;-) )

Comment: [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neglectable) says that _neglectable_ is an archaic form of _negligible_. Some other dictionaries omit _neglectable_ entirely.

Comment: See also https://www.englishforums.com/English/NegligibleVsNeglectable/bvggzm/post.htm

Comment: In a way, "negligible" is about uncountable values, and "neglectable" is about countable ones.

Comment: Are you permitted to bypass it? It's neglectable. Is its value near zero? It's negligible. That sheer nightgown? It's negligeeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't use sentence *B*.  *Negligible* means *small enough to be ignored*.  *Neglectable* is just too archaic, and suggests, to me at least, a piece of fruit you could safely ignore by leaving it on the ground to rot.

Comment: You should add the link to Google Ngrams (as well as an image of the plot) posted above in the comments to support your answer with data.

Answer (score 9):

They seem to mean separate things:

Negligible suggests "so small in size that it can be discarded"

Neglectable suggests a more wilful action, neglecting something or some*one*, because of a perceived lack of worth, not because of size.

It seems a pity to throw away the word "neglectable" just because is used less: it brings up the notion of "neglect", whereas negligible does not.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! This is correct, though it's helpful to add citations if you find relevant ones.